# Ext.msg.alert only the first line rendered

Tags: sencha-touch, alert, extjs

I'm developing an app for Android devices and when I use Ext.msg.alert as follows:

```
Ext.msg.alert('Little fox jumped over something');
```

Only the text "Little fox jumped" is shown in alert because text reaches the right border of the screen and it does not automatically put the rest on second line.

I think this is some kind of auto-fit problem(?).Ext.msg.alert does not make the text fit inside its borders(?).

I've tried

```
Ext.msg.alert('Little fox jumped over something').doComponentLayout();
```

and

```
Ext.msg.alert('Little fox jumped over something').doLayout();
```

But those made no use.

Had any of the folks ever come over this problem? Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Ok got it working now.I had to pass a title.It works with two  attributes.Ext.msg.alert(**'Title',**'Little fox jumped over something');

Comment: Thank you!!  This was my problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The function has 3 parameters:

```
Ext.Msg.alert('Title', 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.', Ext.emptyFn);
```

Try to set the second parameter with your "longer" text. Should look like this: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/?class=Ext.MessageBox